# Why does pandas sum() give wrong answers for Sparse dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sum, sparse-matrix, integer-overflow

In a `Sparse` dataframe, the `sum()` method applied on the whole dataframe gives wrong results, while `sum()` applied to specific column or to a dataframe subset works.

It looks like an overflow issue for `sum()` when applied to the whole dataframe, since type `Sparse[int8, 0]` is chosen for sum result. However, why isn't that the case for the other two scenarios?

Note: Strangely, when run in Anaconda terminal, each scenario gives correct result, while in Pycharms I see the error.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> # Generate standard and sparse DF with binary variable.
>>> # Use int8 to minimize memory usage.
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(50_000, 1)))
>>> sdf = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype(dtype='int8', fill_value=0))
>>> print(df.sum(axis=0))
0    24954
dtype: int64

>>> # Why does this give a wrong answer while the other two work?
>>> print(sdf.sum(axis=0))
0    122
dtype: Sparse[int8, 0]

>>> # Works
>>> print(sdf[0].sum())
24954

>>> # Works
>>> print(sdf[sdf==1].sum())
0    24954.0
dtype: float64
```

Finally, what's a safe way for summing Sparse df columns without going dense or changing the `dtype`? I currently iterate over each column and save the `sum()` result in a dictionary (similar to Scenario 2 in this example), then transform to dataframe, which seems a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think there is probably no good answer to your question. I would rather use [scipy](https://scipy.org/) if I had to deal with [sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(50_000, 3)))
sdf = csr_matrix(df, dtype='int8')
```

```
>>> sdf 
<50000x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int8'>'
    with 75298 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> sdf.sum(axis=0)
matrix([[24963, 25202, 25133]])

>>> pd.DataFrame(sdf.sum(axis=0), columns=df.columns)
       0      1      2
0  24963  25202  25133
```

However, note the ticket opened by a Pandas member: [DEPR: SparseDtype #56518](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/56518)

Comment: Thanks @Corralien, I added to the discussion you linked. I know `scipy` also has sparse structures, but I find them much less intuitive to work with than `pandas` dataframes.

Comment: Sometimes you have to use numpy for some operations like broadcasting even you prefer pandas. If you want to store efficiently you data with high dimensions, you can use xarray. Pandas team should be clear about the usage of their own DType (IntXXDType, StringDType, SparseDType, etc).

Comment: My data has categorical variables, where each might have thousands of cardinal categories, is `xarray` a good choice there? It looks to me like it's for 3+ dimensional arrays, which I do not use. 
Does `numpy` have a significant advantage in broadcasting (e.g. speed or extra functionality) over pandas? I ask since `pandas` also uses broadcasting quite a lot.

Comment: I used your approach with `csr_matrix` as an in-between -- in addition to giving correct results, it is significantly faster especially for `sum(axis=1)`. Thanks again!